# How to I insert a video link within an image file

Tags: html, video

How do I link a video (hosted on a server) to an image? I keep getting the first frame of the video instead of a specific image that I want to display. I also need to get the video to play in the right size on multiple devices. At the moment I can set the height and width but this doesn't adapt to mobiles.

Example:

```
<p><a href="THIS IS THE VIDEO FILE I WANT TO LINK"><img src="/resources/Pictures/Website%20Pages/Members/Club%20TV/Summer%20Camp%20Nutrition.jpg" border="0" alt=""></a><br></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `controls poster` property in order to give your video a poster instead of showing the first frame

`CSS` property `object-fit` to fill the poster based on `width` and `height` of the video

```css
video{
   object-fit: inherit;
}
```

```html
<video width="400px" height=200px" controls poster="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1590573124389-83f2133e0307?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60">
   <source src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190616234019/Canvas.move_.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="https://media.geeksforgeeks.org/wp-content/uploads/20190616234019/Canvas.move_.ogg" type="video/ogg">
 </video>
```

Comment: Any idea why mine doesn't look so clean? Can I add a screenshot to this? My image is in the front, but shifted over to the right. I also get the top part of the script showing up at the top of the image:    video{ object-fit: inherit; }.  I also want to have the video play larger and not confined in the image box... is this possible? I thought about uploading the videos onto YouTube but there are ppl concerned about privacy, even with the privacy settings turned on.

Comment: you have to provide code for that both html and css, in order to remove bugs!